# NavigationController initWithRootViewController crashes app iOS8

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to present a `UIImagePickerController` within a `UINavigationController` with the following code:

```
UIImagePickerController * imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
imagePicker.delegate = self;
imagePicker.showsCameraControls = NO;
imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;
self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;

NSLog(@"HERES THE self.peresntingviewcontorller:: %@", self.presentingViewController);

//[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:^{}];
UINavigationController *cameraNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:imagePicker];  //ERROR HERE
[self presentViewController:cameraNavigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

But I am getting an error where I added the comment "//ERROR HERE", the line where I am trying to initiate a navigation controller with a root view of my `UIImagePickerController` named **imagePicker**. I have no idea what I am doing wrong? any help?

The ERROR is:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing a navigation controller
>   is not supported'

Comment: Where is this code running, and what is the type of `self`?

Comment: I just found that the viewcontroller that is presenting the imagePicker is already in a UINavigationController therefore I cannot present a new navController on top.. >Apple does not allow stacking of navigation Controllers

Comment: Are you using simulator? `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera` is not supported in simulator just in iOS device. For simulator you can test with `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIImagePickerController is derived from UINavigationController, which is why you can't push it onto another UINavigationController (or set as the root view controller).

Comment: Thank you. I was getting really confused here.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to push a navigation controller on another navigation controller. You should instead do something like this:

```
UIImagePickerController * imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
imagePicker.delegate = self;
imagePicker.showsCameraControls = NO;
imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;
self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;

[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```